# H file for InitializeConditionVariable in Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows

I want to use InitializeConditionVariable function in C++ code in Windows 10 and get "InitializeConditionVariable is undefined".
I use include windows.h, but really in
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683469(v=vs.85).aspx
windows 10 is not mentioned.
With include synchapi.h I get No Target Architecture.
Which H file I need to include for this function?

Thanks

Comment: As the page you linked say, "Windows.h" is not the file to include for Windows 10. There is no reason to believe that it could work. (Please copy and paste error messages; don't rephrase. Get them from the Output window, not the Error List.)

Comment: I use Intel compiler. In Visual C++ I get "identifier not found"

Comment: you need simply `#include <windows.h>` but look like `#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0600)` not true in your case. at first file include `#include <sdkddkver.h>`

Comment: I added #include <sdkddkver.h> above #include <windows.h> - it didn't help

Comment: which sdk version you use? how is `_WIN32_WINNT` defined ? which value ?

Comment: _WIN32_WINNT = 0x0502

Comment: but I say you at begin - but look like #if (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0600) not true in your case. - may be you using old SDK - so manually define `#define  _WIN32_WINNT   0x0600` (how minimum) **before** any includes

Comment: Thanks, RbMm - #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600 solved the problem